# Ip Address Message in Console

Tags: javascript, ip-address

I have the following code that I use to retrieve my ip address

```
<script type="text/javascript">var myip;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> console.log(myip) </script>
```

However I get the following message in the console:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

I figure it is because I am making a reference to a js file, however this is a web page that contains html code.

How can I get rid of this message?

Comment: Do you own the `l2.io` domain? If not, you can't do anything about it.

Comment: This is not a web page, this is a simple one line script. But it is transferred with wrong headers. May be you can report this issue to a site owners?